# Laravel: Get Model from Collection by tag

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am currently working on a page to select a menu to order for the next weeksdays.
You can choose between a menu 1 and a menu 2.

For that, I made a Model named Menu, where I query out the different menus from this week.

```
$menus1 = Menu::where('date', '>=', $start->toDateString())
                ->where('date', '<=', $end->toDateString())
                ->where('menu_nr', '=', '1')
                ->orderByRaw('date asc')
                ->get();

$menus2 = Menu::where('date', '>=', $start->toDateString())
                ->where('date', '<=', $end->toDateString())
                ->where('menu_nr', '=', '2')
                ->orderByRaw('date asc')
                ->get();
```

Now I have 2 collections with Menu Models. The goal is to query in this collection again on the webpage, where I display the data of the Model.

For example:

```
$menus1->where('date',$date)->starter_name;
$menus1->where('date',$date)->main_name;
```

Now I get into the problem, that I can't get them out. It always returns a empty Collection.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, where are you getting `$date` from in your example `where('date',$date)`?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.6.33

I get the $date from the index of the helper array. The helper array checks if there is only 1 menu or 2 menus this day.

Comment: you use `->get();` after this you cannot add any query.

Comment: @AGMBALLA is not a query to DB is a query for a collection, it is possible: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where

Comment: Does `$menus1->where('date',$date)->all()` return anything?

Comment: It returns an empty array, but I found the solution, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised, that I need to compare the 'date' column with a Carbon date, because the data type is 'date'.

So i did:

```
$menu = $menus1->where('date', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date))->first();
```

First, because ther is only one.
Now i can get the data with:

```
$menu->starter_name
$menu->main_name
```

Answer (score 0):

u are trying to get one item from a collection try this:

```
$menus1->where('date',$date)->first()->starter_name;
```

Have a look to [Laravel Collection Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)

Comment: The where function already returns an empty collection, even though it is definitely a valid value.

Comment: @GrameJunior what is `date` data type and show me the `$date` value.
Also show me the date column value

Comment: the date column is of the data type 'date' with values in the format of "2018-08-22". The value of $date is the current date in the format "2018-08-22"

Comment: I got it now! Thanks @Froxz, you made me think again with your question about the data type! Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your menus since you are using Laravel's get() method.

Like so:

```
foreach ($menus1 as $m1) {
    if ($m1->date != $date) continue;

    echo $m1->starter_name . ' ' . $m1->main_name;

}

foreach ($menus2 as $m2) {
    if ($m2->date != $date) continue;
    echo $m2->starter_name . ' ' . $m2->main_name;
}
```

Or much better approach is to use the filter method which filters the collection using the given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test. Then loop through it accordingly using each() method:

```
$menus1->filter(function ($m1) use ($date) {
    return $m1->date == $date;
})->each(function($m1) {
    echo $m1->starter_name . ' ' . $m1->main_name;
});

$menus2->filter(function ($m2) use ($date) {
    return $m2->date == $date;
})->each(function($m2) {
    echo $m2->starter_name . ' ' . $m2->main_name;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found a shorter method. Check my answer!

Comment: Oh nice. I did saw it. What you did was probably getting the first record with the given date. I'm thinking with my answer is that if you have multiple records with the given date. :)

Comment: There will be no second Menu1 on any day, so I can go the easier way.